# What type of an algorithm is being used for directory structure scanning?

Tags: operating-systems, search-algorithms, filesystems

So after learning about DFS and BFS yesterday in my class I was curious as to how is scanning on various file system being done. I spent quite a bit of time trying to look for some references on the web, but so far I have failed in doing so. I'm assuming that either DFS or BFS are behind the core "scanning" in some file systems.

There's also Dijkstra's algorithm but as I'm not even sure if file system is a weighted or unweighted tree (ie. number of files being the weight or file size) it's hard to say if it's useful or not because I believe that BFS would be better than Dijkstra if it's unweighted tree.

I hope that someone could clear this up as there just isn't anything specific about it on the web.

Comment: Wait a while. You will learn about dictionary datastructures, and they can be used to create *indices* which enable fast search. Simple tree traversal doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most file systems, a directory lists its entries in a certain order, so reading ("scanning") an individual directory will return its entries in that order.

But when it comes to scanning whole directory structures, there is no such thing as "core scanning": there isn't a common implementation for that.

I think depth-first is more popular; e.g. [*GNU find* only supports depth-first scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/194374/breadth-first-option-in-the-linux-find-utility).  This may be due to depth-first scanning consuming less memory on average; it can't be due to breath-first search being harder to implement, as it's just a matter of treating your list of files to visit as a queue rather than a stack.

Comment: Don't filesystems have indices/tables to speed up searches?

Comment: Raphael: Rarely. On Unix/Linux, fast searching (`locate`) is traditionally provided by a separate database built by a nightly filesystem scan with `find`.

Comment: 1) But surely find does not do a linear scan on the the actual data on the disk? I guess table of contents or inodes are what I had in mind.  2) According to WIkipedia, ext4 uses Htree indices.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'd also like to know if there are any books or theses about that or similar topic. I will have to make a short presentation soon about something that is connected with graphs (Dijkstra's usage in GPS etc.) and I thought that I could do something with directory scanning and DFS/BFS.

Comment: Raphael: `find` reads directories, which are files that contain a mapping from filenames to pointers to files (inodes). So it reads a pointer structure consisting of files of a special type.

Comment: @brajevicm: I don't know about books, but I think it's a good way to illustrate graph traversal algorithms. Filesystems can't really form graphs though unless your traversal follows symlinks, so you may get questions about that unless you cover it. Not sure how this is in NTFS.

Comment: @Raphael there are in-memory caches and indexes to speed up searches, but their operation is complicated by (dynamically changing) access permissions that give each user a possibly different subtree.  So it's difficult to build a simple index structure.